# Why am I unable to ask questions on main site?

Tags: support

I am noticing what seems to be a glitch/bug on the main site, where I am now unable to ask a question because the "Post Your Question" button is disabled.

[image: Post Your Question is disabled]

I have correctly filled in the question title, details and tags. I have no problems on other SE network sites, such as Stack Overflow or The Workplace, and (as you can see) *here* on Sports.SE meta. I don't seem to recall having done anything unsportsmanlike (Heh, couldn't resist shoehorning this witty remark here), so I don't think I have been *banned* from asking questions.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Try refreshing the page? There's no reason that I know of for that button to be disabled unless the Javascript failed to run.

Comment: Glad to see you back on the main site. http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/is-batsman-allowed-to-score-leg-byes-by-kicking-the-ball-while-pretending-to-h